# How to setup the Email piping in WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, plugin-development, email

I am trying to Create a Ticket plugin that supports Email Piping but I am unable to set up the mail server through the plugin. If anyone knows how to set up the email server please help.

Comment: what do you mean by email piping?

Comment: @TomJNowell Through Email Piping A user can send an email to my support mail address and that email will be converted to a post type.

Comment: I don't believe setting up a mail server is something that can be done from WordPress, you can build your plugin to check an inbox at regular intervals but it can't create an inbox or an email server. Most people do this via dedicated services or they do it via tools such as IFTTT or Zapier

Comment: There are already some plugins that support email piping but those are premium plugins and so I want to create a plugin of my own that supports Email Piping but I don't how to get started and I don't find many resources regarding that too.

Comment: it's not possible to set up an email inbox from a plugin without some sort of 3rd party inbox service. For email piping you need to read an inbox and process what comes in, but you can't create an inbox from a plugin, you would need an email inbox service like GMail, and to set it up on that domain you need host intervention, a plugin can't do that for you. There is more to this than meets the eye, and those plugins that claim they can do email piping do not do all the parts. The most useful things you find will likely never mention email piping as it's a niche term

Comment: you can read an inbox via a plugin, but you cannot create an inbox or set up the domain to receive email without user intervention at the host level. How you would read an email inbox is a different matter though, and something you should ask about on stackoverflow as it isn't a WordPress specific question.